# Script to highlight the current page when there is more than one page (e.g. page 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following script to highlight the current page on a tumblr blog, which I got from here: http://www.eznetu.com/current-link.html

```
$(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
```

This works great, but there is one problem: the link must be identical to the current URL or it will not work. In other words, if the link points to blog.tumblr.com/tagged/red, it works fine, but if the user naviagtes to the next page, i.e. blog.tumblr.com/tagged/red/page/2, it will not work.

I am absolutely clueless about  javascript, and was wondering if there is a way to insert a wildcard so that it picks up cases like the one outlined above. I would greatly appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: `if window.location.href.indexOf($(this).prop('href')) > -1) {`

Comment: @cale_b: wouldn't that always match a link to the site root?

Comment: you can use $("a[href^='"+location.href.replace(/page\/\d+$/,"")+"']").addClass("current")

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for your help. I tried your suggestion, but it only works on the first page; i.e. blog.tumblr.com/tagged/red/ When I go to blog.tumblr.com/tagged/red/page/2 it no longer works. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a bit by using the CSS [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
$('a[href*=' + window.location.href + ']').addClass('current');
```

Comment: Wouldn't `a[href^=` or `ahref[*=` be more appropriate?

Comment: Just to be clear to people reading this answer, it would be nice to explain that the `*` means *contains*, and the `^` means *starts with*

Comment: Thank you both so much for the prompt reply. I tried both suggestions, but I am not getting the desired result. As I mentioned, I am absolutely clueless about javascript, so it could just be an error in my syntax. Here is what I tried:<br /> <script>
$(function(){
$('a[href*=' + window.location.href + ']').addClass('current');
    }
});
</script><br />Does that look alright?

Comment: @NDG What is the value of window.location.href?  Maybe you could update your question with some more details.

Comment: @Sneaky Thanks again for the help. I would be happy to provide more information. Are you asking for the URL of the page? If so, you can see it here: http://pocketchronicles-qa.tumblr.com/tagged/tag+1